# trojan testing within upload ssh/ftp

Tags: debian, trojan

We had yesterday an trojan upload on our debian lenny server. It cost 6 hours of repairing several sites + local pc's. At 1 of the local pc I discovered that the firewall was set to disabled. The pc was also infected with this Trojan:JS/BlacoleRef.W
Why do this pc had an ftp account to our server? For daily upload the shipping tracking to the server + weekly upload of a new newsletter.

Question: is there a existing solution on the server to test all the ftp/ssh uploads. This should help us very much.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is, obviously, to keep **all** your machines clean, even the clients.

#### FTP

It depends on the deamon you use. Typically there is no server-side scan of what's uploaded, but [proftpd](http://www.proftpd.org/) has a modular architecture and you can write your mod_content_checker that
inspect the uploads and rejects files that don't line up with your policy.

You could also scan the files with `clamv`.

#### SSH / rsync

You can use a [forced command](http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/jpmg/ssh/authorized_keys_howto.html) with a script that scans the files.

but keep **all** your machines clean.